# C++ BST tree insert a string

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am trying to create a BST whose data is a string.. however, it doesn't seem to like the string value..if i change the data type to int, the code works.. i am not sure why..can someone help?
here is the code

```
// BST.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

// An AVL tree node
struct Node
{
    string key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int height;
    int counter;
};

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b);

// A utility function to get height of the tree
int height(struct Node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return N->height;
}

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
NULL left and right pointers. */
struct Node* newNode(const string& key)
{
    struct Node* node = (struct Node*)
        malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = nullptr;
    node->counter = 0;
    node->height = 1; // new node is initially added at leaf
    return(node);
}

// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *rightRotate(struct Node *y)
{
    struct Node *x = y->left;
    struct Node *T2 = x->right;

    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    // Update heights
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return x;
}

// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct Node *leftRotate(struct Node *x)
{
    struct Node *y = x->right;
    struct Node *T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    // Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}

// Get Balance factor of node N
int getBalance(struct Node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}

// Recursive function to insert key in subtree rooted
// with node and returns new root of subtree.
struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, string key)


{
    /* 1. Perform the normal BST insertion */
    if (node == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    else // Equal keys are not allowed in BST
    {
        node->counter++;
        return node;
    }
    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left),
        height(node->right));

    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor
    node to check whether this node became
    unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then
    // there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
        return rightRotate(node);

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
        return leftRotate(node);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key)
    {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key)
    {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

// A utility function to print preorder traversal
// of the tree.
// The function also prints height of every node
void preOrder(struct Node *root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        cout << root->key << endl;;
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
}

/* Drier program to test above function*/
int main()
{
    struct Node *root = nullptr;

    /* Constructing tree given in the above figure */

    root = insert(root, "a");
    root = insert(root, "bc");
    root = insert(root, "DE");
    root = insert(root, "op");
    root = insert(root, "lo");
    root = insert(root, "mp");

    /*root = insert(root, 10);
    root = insert(root, 20);
    root = insert(root, 30);
    root = insert(root, 40);
    root = insert(root, 50);
    root = insert(root, 25);*/

    printf("Preorder traversal of the constructed AVL"
        " tree is \n");
    preOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What doesn't work ? What changed when you changed data type ? Your question is like "nothing works. please help"

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  BTW, that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is here:

`struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

This will not work correctly.  The `Node` class has `std::string` as a member, and using `malloc` to create dynamic instances will not call the constructor for `std::string`.  The `malloc` function knows nothing about `C++` constructors or objects.

In `C++`, there is something called a `POD` (*Plain-Old-Data*) type, which basically is a `C` compatible type.  The `malloc` call will only work correctly for `POD` types.  When you changed the `Node` member from `int` to `std::string`, you changed `Node` from being a POD type to a non-POD type.  Once your type is non-POD, functions such as `malloc` to create instances will not work as you expect.

The `malloc` call just allocates memory, and nothing else.  It doesn't know how to call the constructor for C++ classes (such as `std::string`), thus your `Node` object has an invalid, unconstructed `std::string`.  Using it causes undefined behavior to occur.

To alleviate this, use `new`, not `malloc` to create dynamic instances of `Node`, since `new` calls the constructor for the non-POD type.

`Node* node = new Node();`

Even if `Node` were POD, you should use `new` instead of `malloc`.

---

You also don't need to specify `struct` everywhere.  Using `struct` like that is a holdover from `C`, and is not required for `C++`.

Example:  Instead of this:

```
struct Node *rightRotate(struct Node *y)
{
    struct Node *x = y->left;
    struct Node *T2 = x->right;
```

this is all you need for `C++`:

```
Node *rightRotate(Node *y)
{
    Node *x = y->left;
    Node *T2 = x->right;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, one more question if you don't mind.. i revised my code to Node* node=new Node(); as advised.. however, it creates a memory leak ... not sure how to free that node.....

Comment: That is a completely different question.  Without going into detail, use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`.